# RML report openerp 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, rml

How to get the field which is present in sale.order in invoice report. So invoice report use the model account.invoice, if i add a function in report.py it allow only self.cr,self.uid because we are not using osv.memory. So how to get the value of cust_ref_value from sale.order to invoice report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can track from the `Source Document`

In `report.py` we need to make a function and pass origin in it.

```
def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
    super(your_report_calss_name, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context)
    self.localcontext.update({
        'time': time, 
        'get_cust_ref_val': self._get_cust_ref_val,
    })
```

This method will check like origin is SO or PO or OUT/###:SO### or IN/###:PO### so following case be here

```
def _get_cust_ref_val(self, origin)
    if 'SO' in origin:
        if 'OUT/' in origin:
            so_name = str(origin).split(':')[1]
            sale_id = self.pool.get('sale.order').search(self.cr, self.uid, [('name', '=', so_name)]
            if sale_id:
                sale = self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(self.cr, self.uid, sale_id)
                return sale.cust_ref_value
        else:
            sale_id = self.pool.get('sale.order').search(self.cr, self.uid, [('name', '=', origin)]
            if sale_id:
                sale = self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(self.cr, self.uid, sale_id)
                return sale.cust_ref_value
    else:
        return ''
```

and from the rml side

```
[[ get_cust_ref_val(inv.origin) ]]
```